# Can I make the entire activity scroll instead of the ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I'm populating an activity with a ListView that sometimes exceeds the window size vertically. Instead of the user being able to scroll the ListView, I want the ListView to just take up the space it needs and let the users scroll in the activity instead. Is this possible?

Here is an image for clarification: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxA0Z.jpg

On both sides there is a ListView containing 8 elements, only the right one takes up the space it needs to show the list fully though, pushing the other views down and making the entire activity scrollable.

Comment: What? The two scenarios you're describing are equal.

Comment: I knew this was going to be difficult to explain :) By default, if a ListViews horizontal size(many elements) exceeds an activities window size(the device window), it becomes scrollable. I want the activity to become scrollable instead, so that the ListView just spits out all its elements. It looks much more cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: I'm still not with you, buddy. :-)

Comment: Look at my edit above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the methods [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) and addFooterView to add views before and after the ListView.

To add several views, first put the views in a Layout or ViewGroup and add that ViewGroup as the header or footer view (ViewGroup is a subclass of View).

Comment: Thanks, kind of messy but then again so is my problem :)

Comment: A little fiddly if you have several views to go in the header or footer but worth it.

Answer (score -2):

-have you tried to put your scroll element as top level element in your layout .xml?

Something like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Seems like ScrollView doesn't know how to fill_parent, now the ListView just displays two elements and a veeeeery long scrollbar.

Comment: A ListView should never be placed inside a ScrollView!

Comment: This will not work. There are hacks available to make this sort of thing work but it's more than just adding a scrollview in XML. For anyone interested: http://nex-otaku-en.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-put-listview-in-scrollview.html however I think the selected answer is probably the way to go.